# Copy/Paste from last row in one table in worksheet to another last row

Tags: excel, vba

My issue is the destination. The copied row goes directly to the same row# in the other worksheet, as opposed to the last row of that worksheets table.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim table As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set data = Worksheets("Data Input")
    Set table = Worksheets("Data Tables")

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Goes to last row containing data in sheet Data Input
    lastRow = data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Same as above but for Data Tables
    sidsteRow = table.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Removes error msg when copy/pasting
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If data.Cells(lastRow, 4) <> "" Then

        data.Cells(lastRow, 1).Copy table.Cells(sidsteRow, 1)
        data.Cells(lastRow, 2).Copy table.Cells(sidsteRow, 2)
        data.Cells(lastRow, 3).Copy table.Cells(sidsteRow, 3)
        data.Cells(lastRow, 4).Copy table.Cells(sidsteRow, 4)
        data.Cells(lastRow, 6).Copy table.Cells(sidsteRow, 5)

    End If


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: It is good to avoid Copy - Paste. So, you can simple write: `table.Cells(sidsteRow + 1, 1) = data.Cells(lastRow, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me with one mistake: It should be

```
sidsteRow = table.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Otherwise you are just pasting over the last row instead appending it after the last row of the destination.

If your intent was to copy overtop of the last row, then it works exactly as intended in my testing.